# CSS animation rules disappear in Firefox resulting in no animation

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I've just set up a few css animations and everything is running smoothly in Chrome and Safari however Firefox doesn't appear to be playing nice.

The following code:

```
#clock-animation .hour {
  -webkit-animation: anti-spin 30s infinite;
  animation: anti-spin 30s infinte;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Appears to be displaying as:

```
#clock-animation .hour {
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
```

When viewed in Firebug and consequently the animation isn't playing.

I'm a tad confused as to why this is and nothing appears to be fixing it.

Here are the keyframes used too:

```
@-webkit-keyframes anti-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes anti-spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

According to http://shouldiprefix.com/ the -moz prefix isn't needed for keyframes, animation or transform. Nor is the -webkit which is only needed for Chrome and Safari. Any help would be great.

**Edit:** Just to mention that the IDs and classes are part of an inline SVG file. I'm not sure if that is relevant or not?

**Edit:** Heres a link to a demo https://jsfiddle.net/0Lha6dfg/ (Works fine in Chrome / Safari but not in FF (36.0.1))

Comment: We'd probably need a demo but you might want to review this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052074/transform-origin-not-working-on-firefox/29052844#29052844

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just tried playing with that solution but unfortunately I've not had any success. I've now attached a link to a demo at the end of the question.

Comment: As per the answer below, you have some typos for 'infinite', when you correct those, the other transform issues come into play. GL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to write out your animation shorthand property in full, do not skip properties. Shorthand format from [w3 specs](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp):

```
div {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Becomes:

```
div {
    animation: example 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
}
```

---

So in your example add the `animation-delay`:

```
animation: anti-spin 30s linear infinite;
```

Should be:

```
animation: anti-spin 30s linear 0s infinite;
```

Also watch out for typos, in some places you have "infinte" instead of "infinite".

Comment: Typically something simple like that. Thanks a lot for your help!