# Velocity JS SVG transform origin issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, css, svg, velocity.js

I would like to rotate an `SVG group` from the center using `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` using Velocity JS. This works fine in Chrome but I've noticed that the transform origin is wrong in `IE and Firefox`. I've tried setting an extra transform origin value and also tried setting the transform origin as pixels instead of % etc but with no luck. Can anyone explain how to fix this problem?

I have a demo here http://codepen.io/styler/pen/wBRPEa?editors=101

**Code snippet**

**CSS**

```
.box {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var box = document.querySelector('.js-box');    
setInterval(function() {
  Velocity(box,
    {
      rotateZ: 0
    },
    {
      duration: 600
    },
    "easeIn"
  );
  Velocity(box,
    {
      rotateZ: 360
    },
    {
      duration: 1200
    },
    "easeOut"
  );
}, 2200);
```

I've tried rotating a plain `div` and the correct transform-origin works fine, seems to be SVG related.

Comment: Firefox does not support transform-origin with percentages for SVG content. Use some other unit.

Comment: to improve performance into IE and firefox (and chrome), i use only CSS transformation matrix instead of SVG transformation attributes

Comment: ...and even if FF did support percentages it still uses a different `transform-origin` implementation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052074/transform-origin-not-working-on-firefox/29052844#29052844

Comment: See also - https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/

Comment: CSS transformation matrix and SVG transformation has the same performance in Firefox and Chrome.