# SVG - Animation around center with Snap.svg / velocity.js (Firefox Issue)

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg, velocity.js

I know there are a couple of threads with similar problems out there,
but I couldn't resolve my issue.

In Chrome/Safari this works fine; the line rotates around the end of the pen.

http://codepen.io/kkern/pen/xVYQox

In Firefox the rotation looks odd. I know that transform-origin doesn't
work in Firefox like in Chrome, so I tried it with Snap.SVG in an attempt to resolve the browser differences with no success.

VELOCITY

```js
$('#svg-velocity #se-line')
    .velocity({rotateZ:10 })
    .delay(900)
    .velocity("reverse", {delay:900})
    .velocity({rotateZ:-10})
    .delay(600)
    .velocity("reverse", {complete: animVel});
```

SNAP SVG

```js
var s = Snap("#svg-snap .svg-design-i");
var line = s.select("#se-line");

var box = line.getBBox();
var cx = box.width/2+box.x;
var cy = box.height/2+box.y;

line.animate({ transform: "r15," + cx + ',' + cy}, 1000,  mina.easeIn, function() {
    line.animate({ transform: "r0," + cx + ',' + cy}, 1000, mina.easeIn, function() {
        animSnap();
    })
});
```

Firefox Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I assume your code is missing transform-box. Firefox only supports transform-box in its developer edition and Chrome has the wrong default value for transform-box

Comment: Hi thank you. That doesn`t change very much. I`m looking for a cross browser solution. Thats the reason I tried it with snap.svg. There is a similiar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170197/velocity-js-svg-transform-origin-issue-in-firefox-and-ie

Comment: Snap version works fine for me in Firefox & Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure? I updated the thread above with an screenshot. You can see that the line moves inside the pen (Firefox 45.0.2)

Comment: If you want a cross browser solution stop depending on transform-origin. I.e. Make the object rotate about 0,0

Comment: Ok, Im totally fine with that. That should the snap.svg thing do, but how?